# Bash list files as {path + file}

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ls

I want to search for a file that has 1033 bytes of size. Therefore, I write `ls -lRA`, which outputs around 200 files, in around 20 folders. When I grep for the file with `ls -lRA | grep 1033` I get one element alone, `-rw-r-----  1 root bandit5 1033 Dec  3 08:14 .file2`. However, there are 20 files with this name, so finding this one is a hard task.

My idea is to get an output such as `-rw-r-----  1 root bandit5 1033 Dec  3 08:14 ./direcctory1/.file2`, is it possible?

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use GNU find. Search from current directory:

```
find . -size 1033c -ls
```

Output (e.g.)

```
110578      3 -rwxrwxrwx   1 root     root         1033 Dec  6 10:10 ./direcctory1/.file2
```

See: `man find`

Comment: Can you explain why you removed the duplicate marking only to post an answer suggesting exactly the solution from the duplicate?

Comment: This is about the search of a file with a certain size and not the output of the file sizes.